# IPython - cycle through blocks in input history?

Tags: python, ipython, python-idle

Say I input the following:

```
def foo():
    print(2)
```

Then later, when I want to edit my function, I press the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow key to rewrite it, and that cycles through my inputs one line at a time (i.e. first it shows `print(2)`, then `def foo():`). Is there any way to make it cycle through blocks of code the way IDLE does it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this under IPython 0.12.1. Up key will flip the whole block of function `foo`.

Comment: I'm using IPython 0.13 on windows, I don't know if that might be relevant.

Comment: may be, mine is under Linux. Did you check it out in other terminal emulators?

Comment: It might be harder to get that working on Windows, because the real readline library isn't available. As @DerekLitz suggests, you can use the Qt console, which will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Since IPython has stopped using readline, this issue has come back, the "solution" is to use `PageUp` and `PageDown` instead `C-up` and `C-down`.

Comment: PageUp/PageDown do weird things on the console. I'm on `macOS`

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with an earlier version of iPython on Linux (11 I think).  New versions do not do this.

I currently still use 11, and my solution was to just use the iPython qtconsole instead which does what you want.  I would assume it would do the same on Windows.