# Cycle through ipython "history" with one keystroke per item even when multiple lines

Tags: python, ipython

I have a question similar to this one from 2012  [IPython - cycle through blocks in input history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802555/ipython-cycle-through-blocks-in-input-history) - but whose answers are likewise over eight years old. That is: how to cycle through `ipython` history items without say hitting up-arrow key once per every line in a 30 line block.

Apparently `ipython` has not used `readline` for many years: so what is the way (if any) to achieve this ? I am on `IPython 7.13.0`

**Update** Hmm just playing around with different key combinations I found that `CMD-Up/Down Arrow` physically scrolls the cursor through the historical *outputs*  . Below is an approximation that the `In[10]` is highlighted in yellow briefly after having hit `CMD-UpArrow` three times from the current `In[13]`:

[image]

It is not the same as my question that is looking to scroll through the historical commands *in place*  /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be specific to the `macOS` `Terminal` app handling of `PageUp` / `PageDown`. `iTerm2` instead has the desired behavior of scrolling the history using those keystrokes.

Two questions remain that I will dig into further:

- Are there any settings on `Terminal` app to adjust this behavior
- What about when using a `macBook Pro` that does not have PgUp/PgDown` keys?

**Update**  Messing around further with key combinations I found that `Shift-[PageUp/PageDn]` get the job done on `Terminal.app`.  Well at least that works on an external keyboard. Not sure yet how to achieve that just on the `macBook Pro` native keyboard.  Oh- I need to press `Fn-[Up/Dn]arrow`

Answer (score 3):

Page Up and Page Down do that.

Also, [here's](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/6.5.0/config/shortcuts/index.html) the (full?) list of IPython shortcuts, which is where I found those shortcuts.

Comment: PageUp and PageDown simply scroll the output in the  (macOS) Terminal (completly independently of ipython) : they do not scroll the ipython history.  Is there a setting to change for this to work properly?

Comment: btw are you the aka famous `Lightness Races in Orbit` ?   And .. thanks for that list I'm looking at it.

Comment: No, that's someone else. As for the terminal settings, I don't know why that would happen or how to adjust it.

Comment: Which OS are you running on that PageUp/PageDown work to do this?

Comment: Aha i just discovered: it is specific to `Terminal` on `macOS`  - `iTerm2` does work the way you describe